# What is this insect I found in northern Europe?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found this one in my bed in Northern Europe.

[image: insect]

[image: insect]

Around 6 mm long (5 mm body + 1 mm nozzle). Seems to have 6 legs. The back looks a bit like black-brown camouflage, the legs are red-brown, the nozzle is black.

Could this be some kind of bed bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Small black slow-moving insect showing up in the home](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/69598/small-black-slow-moving-insect-showing-up-in-the-home)

Comment: The nose is a dead giveaway: it's a weevil. See [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/56204/16866) for identificaron and info on bed bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not a bedbug. It is a weevil, family Curculionidae. A beetle, and not normally found indoors. It looks a bit like *Baris*, but I cannot tell from the picture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baris_(weevil)

Comment: great, thanks! The Weevil type looks definitely right. Not sure about Baris though, it looked a bit more like one of these Lixus Junci https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weevil#/media/File:Lixusjunci.png (the picture i provided doesn't really give a lot detail, sorry)