# What is the name/type/species of this insect?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Facts:

1. Found in a bathtub in western Washington (state) (the pacific northwest).
2. 3/16-1/4" long, 1/8-3/16 thick.
3. Gray colored.
4. No elongated noise but two antennas.
5. No pets in home, older 1969 build (vented crawlspace).
6. Found on main floor (crawlspace underneath).

This seems like a weevil or a carpet beetle. Most interested in making sure it’s not harmful.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Species ID questions need to include a photo, size, location, and as much other information as possible. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info). If you update your post with such information, it can be reopened and you'll be able to receive an answer.

Comment: In the meantime: act fast to find your open or damaged container of stored cereal grains, pasta, or similar.

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/69598/small-black-slow-moving-insect-showing-up-in-the-home

Comment: @theforestecologist thank you. Post updated.

Comment: This is much better, but is there any chance of getting close-ups (from multiple angles)? Borrowing a good camera with a macro lens or a phone with a better camera would make it much more likely you can get a precise answer.

Comment: @tyersome we released the insect to the wild. I'll use the suggestion on the next one!